# How to create a gitlab CI pipeline where tear down is done regardless of the status of previous jobs?

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have a following gitlab pipeline which runs integration tests:

```
default:
  image: ImageFoo


before_script:
  - . ./CI/before_script.sh

stages:
  - code-analyze
  - build
  - infra
  - integration-test
  - tear-down

.base:
  tags:
    - gitlab-runners-220707-195833-small

check-style:
  extends: .base
  stage: code-analyze
  script: ./gradlew styleCheck

build-code:
  extends: .base
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./gradlew clean
    - ./gradlew build -x detekt
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/fooA/build/libs/fooA.jar
      - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/fooB/build/libs/fooB.jar
      - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/fooC/build/libs/fooC.jar

build-infra:
  extends: .base
  stage: infra
  script:
    -  . ./terraform/test_apply.sh -w foo
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: $CI_PROJECT_DIR/build.env
  needs:
    - job: build-code
      artifacts: true

run-integration-test:
  extends: .base
  stage: integration-test
  script:
    - . ./CI/.variables
    - ./gradlew integrationTest -D$A -D$B -D$C
  needs:
    - job: build-infra
      artifacts: true

destroy-infra:
    extends: .base
    stage: tear-down
    script:
      - . ./terraform/test_destroy.sh -w foo
```

Now in this case following scenarios can happen on failure and I need to `destroy-infra`:

- `build-infra` failed
- `run-integration-tests` failed

how can I make sure that `destroy-infra` runs both in case of success and failure scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `when: always` to teardown after test.

```yaml
destroy-infra:
  when: always
  # ...
```

To handle the case where `build-infra` fails, you can use an `after_script`:

```yaml
build-infra:
  # ...
  after_script:
    - |
      if [[ "$CI_JOB_STATUS" == "failed" ]]; then
         . ./terraform/test_destroy.sh -w foo
      fi
```

Comment: if we use when:always it would run destroy-infra step even in case of failure. If we are adding when: always wouldn't after_script becomes redundant in this case ?

Comment: @CyberPunk even if you add `when: always`, I believe the job can be blocked by the intermediate `integration-test` stage not running because the previous stage (`infra`) failed. But I could be mistaken on the behavior.

Comment: in this case integration-test depends on infra. If infra fails integration-test would be skipped and would still run tear-down

Comment: In which case, yes, it seems the `after_script` would be redundant @CyberPunk